# Authorizing an application with Oauth and Python

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build an application that will use data from multiple social services.  The user will need to authorize their accounts to be accessed across these multiple services (e.g. facebook, twitter, foursquare) using oauth.

I don't really need the users to login with these accounts, really it is just allowing their data from the api to be pulled.

I know I need to use oauth, but I am having trouble finding a basic example of how to do this type of thing (a lot of examples exist for logging in with oauth).

I have been trying the python-oath2 library.

Does anyone have any recommendation for a good tutorial or example of doing this type of thing in python, and if possible django.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why reinvent the wheel? There is a plethora of reusable applications that have this implemented. You can find a comparison here: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Why not give [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) a try? We use this in production for this exact purpose. Although you don't need to require the user to login with your app via the provider, you're going to redirect to the provider, where they'll be asked to authenticate your application. Assuming they accept (or even if they don't), they'll be redirected back to your application, i.e. via the `redirect_uri` or `oauth_callback`, there you'll ensure they authorized your app and then proceed with whatever housekeeping you need to do, e.g. saving some info about the user in your database. Try [the examples](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples) and also pay particular attention to the [Facebook example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook). Now the Facebook example is intended for authorization with the example web app, but the same pattern can be used for what you're trying to do. (You just won't be having them login in via Facebook, for instance. However, the flow can be and probably should be identical, sans database operations and template login lingo.)